# reading characters from buffer

Tags: c, fgetc, getc

I am scanning strings as input , i am using getline to do so e.g

```
char *lajna=NULL;
size_t dlzka=0;
getline(&lajna,&dlzka,stdin);
```

and i want to read first char using fgetc , i tried to do

```
test=fgetc(lajna);
```

but it throws error

> cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ for argument ‘1’ to
>   ‘int fgetc(FILE*)’
>        ciarka=fgetc(&lajna);

i checked it up and found nothing how to read chars from buffer like this, what is the right way?

Comment: `char *sp = lajna; test=*sp++;`

Answer (score 2):

See the prototype of `fgetc()`:

```
   int fgetc(FILE *stream);
```

It takes a `FILE*` as argument but you are passing `char*`. Hence, the error. (The error message suggests you actually have it like: `test=fgetc(&lajna);`)

To read characters from `lajna`, you don't need to use any function or special mechanism. You can simply index into it:

```
char ch = lajna[0]; // first char
```

and so on.

Or you can use a loop to read all chars.

```
for(i=0; lajna[i]; i++) {  //until the null terminator '\0'
   char ch = lajna[i];
}
```

Comment: i  would like to use sscanf on that buffer , and i need to get rid of first character.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to use `sscanf()`. If you simply to ignore the first char then do: `char *str = lajna +1;` and use `str`. If you want to make a *copy* then use: `char buf[dlzka]; strcpy(buf, lajna+1);`

Comment: If you want to use `sscanf` and ignore the first character one option is: `sscanf(&lajna[1], ...)`. This assumes `lajna` has at least one character (and the NUL terminator). Or `sscanf(lajna, "%*c%s", ..)`, the `*` format specifier means parse but ignore that input.

Comment: this does not help my code at all , is there any way how to use fgetc on that buffer?  the "%*c" mess up it pretty badly.

Comment: "is there any way how to use fgetc on that buffer?" - No. It's *not* possible. You are asking something that doesn't make sense. `fgetc()` reads from a *stream*, not from a buffer. `sscanf()` can be used to read a char but that's pointless to a single character from a buffer.